# Visualforce ajax Uncaught Error: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9

Tags: visualforce, ajax, chrome

I have got a visualforce page which uses ajax components actionFunction and actionStatus. Whenever the actionFunction is called, I use actionStatus to show the status. The onstart works fine, but the onstop does not fire instead the following error is thrown in chrome console "Uncaught Error: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9".

Anyone come across this?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the VF markup? Are you using any addition Javascript or JS Libraries, such as jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this error is rerendering apex:tab from the actionFunction, apparently salesforce does not support rerendering the tab component, the solution is to wrap your tab contents inside apex:outputPanel and rerender that instead.